# COUNT(*) returning false results when no applicable rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(iup.user_id) AS user_plans_count
FROM #__iop_user_plans iup
INNER JOIN #__iop_plan ip ON iup.iop_id = ip.id
WHERE `iup`.`state` = 1 AND `iup`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL AND `iup`.`accepted` = 0
```

When there are no rows applicable, MySQL still returns one result containing ONLY the count. How can I change my query to only return the count if it is bigger than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job

```
SELECT *, COUNT(iup.user_id) AS user_plans_count
FROM #__iop_user_plans iup
INNER JOIN #__iop_plan ip ON iup.iop_id = ip.id
WHERE `iup`.`state` = 1 AND `iup`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL 
AND `iup`.`accepted` = 0 
HAVING user_plans_count>0
```

Comment: I waited for the time limit to pass. Which was 9 mins, about 30 mins ago. :)